# PHP string-embedded array format: "${arr[0]}" vs "{$arr[0]}"

Tags: php, arrays, string

In PHP, you can embed an array directly in a (double-quoted) string, but it looks like there are two ways to do it; for example:

```
$arr[0]="foobar";
echo "${arr[0]}";
echo "{$arr[0]}";
```

They both seem to work, but what is the difference? Is either better?

<sup>(It’s frustratingly difficult to look this up due to Google’s lack of special-character support, but I have seen both formats in use.)</sup>

Comment: @Sean The syntax for variable variables would be `"${$arr[0]}"`. Note the extra `$`.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [PHP documentation on Strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex), both `"${arr[0]}"` and `"{$arr[0]}"` are shown as valid examples.  However, after this, only `"{$arr[0]}"` syntax is used.  So you would *assume*, that this is the "preferred" syntax.

Comment: Side note: this is called complex string parsing (curly syntax).

Answer (score 1):

None of them is "better". They are just the same thing expressed in slight different syntax. Check the manual page about string parsing: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing. It is a very good documentation page, nothing more to say.

Answer (score 0):

Both work because both are valid. From [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> **Complex (curly) syntax**
>
> This isn't called complex because the syntax is complex, but because
>   it allows for the use of complex expressions.
>
> Any scalar variable, array element or object property with a string
>   representation can be included via this syntax. Simply write the
>   expression the same way as it would appear outside the string, and
>   then wrap it in { and }. Since { can not be escaped, this syntax will
>   only be recognised when the $ immediately follows the {. Use {\$ to
>   get a literal {$.

```
// Won't work, outputs: This is { fantastic}
echo "This is { $great}";

// Works, outputs: This is fantastic
echo "This is {$great}";
echo "This is ${great}";

// Works
echo "This square is {$square->width}00 centimeters broad."; 


// Works, quoted keys only work using the curly brace syntax
echo "This works: {$arr['key']}";
```